# How to remove gnome-core

Tags: gui

I installed gnome-core using `sudo apt-get install gnome-core`. But now I want to uninstall it and switch over to other desktop environments. Does anyone know how to do this and what are the other uis you would recommend. This is for a beaglebone- So a light weight Ui would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Is `sudo apt-get remove gnome-core` works?

---

With other guis you can use

---

## KDE

```
sudo apt-get install x-window-system-core kde
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install kdm
```

for KDM login screen

---

## LXDE

type in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lxde/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lxde
```